# How do list all keys including disabled from Azure Key vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

This only list key which are enabled

```
credential = AzureCliCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=f"https://{keyvault}.vault.azure.net", credential=credential)
return secret_client.list_properties_of_secrets()
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do list all keys including disabled from Azure Key vault

Here is the updated code to list all keys, including **disabled** ones, in the `Key Vault`.

```py
    from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
    from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient
    
    # Authenticate to Azure using a suitable credential (e.g., DefaultAzureCredential)
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    
    # Connect to your Key Vault
    client = KeyClient(vault_url="https://venkat-vault.vault.azure.net", credential=credential)
    
    # List all keys, including disabled ones
    all_keys = client.list_properties_of_keys()
    
    for key in all_keys:
        print(f"Key Name: {key.name}")
        versions = client.list_properties_of_key_versions(key.name)
        for version in versions:
            print(f"  - Version: {version.name}, Enabled: {version.enabled}")
```

Keys created in Key vault.

[image]

After running the above code, the displayed keys include those that are **disabled** from the specified **key vault**

[image]